# Javascript complete type list clarification?

Tags: javascript, types

[Dmitry Baranovskiy's blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/08/27/javascript-types/) (creator of [Raphael](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/raphael)) says that there are only 6 types in Javascript:

`Object`, `Number`, `String`, `Boolean`, `Null`, and `Undefined`.

Each can easily  be checked via (for example):

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(undefined) //"[object Undefined]"
```

But what about:

```
Object.prototype.toString.apply(new Date()) //"[object Date]"

Object.prototype.toString.apply(/a/)//"[object RegExp]"
```

...and `Array`, `Functions` also...

Are they different? Why are they not mentioned?

PS:

Is it related to the less-specific check like:

`>>typeof [] //"object"` ?

Comment: First ones are primitives.
The ones you mention are native objects: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Native_objects

They are all of type "Object"

Comment: @mishik so how many types are? 6? ( each of testing starts with "object"]

Comment: Have a look here: http://es5.github.io/#x8-toc. There are only 6 data types you can interact with. *"An ECMAScript language type corresponds to values that are directly manipulated by an ECMAScript programmer using the ECMAScript language. The ECMAScript language types are Undefined, Null, Boolean, String, Number, and Object."* Functions, arrays and regular expressions are all objects.

Comment: @FelixKling thanks. please consider convert this to an answer. (Q :are you saying that this method `[Object.prototype.toString.apply]` is not the right method for type checking ?)

Comment: @RoyiNamir Is your question answered for now? Then mark it as it is! :)

Comment: [There is no Javascript.](http://PointedEars.de/es-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ECMAScript Language Specification, 5.1 Edition, §8](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8):

> An ECMAScript language type corresponds to values that are directly manipulated by an ECMAScript programmer using the ECMAScript language. **The ECMAScript language types are [Undefined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.1), [Null](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.2), [Boolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.3), [String](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.4), [Number](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5), and [Object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.6)**.

From this definition it seems that functions, arrays and regular expressions are of the `Object` type.

This might seem strange for functions, since you can do something with them you can't do with other objects: You can call them. However, this characteristic is simply an internal property which not all objects have (also in §8):

> Table 9 — Internal Properties Only Defined for Some Objects
>
> `[[Call]]` Executes code associated with the object. Invoked via a function call expression.

Answer (score 0):

> Node, Element and HTMLElement are not types, just like Array, Date and RegExp they are just objects.

http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2012/08/27/javascript-types/#comment-6038